# how to survey and show every single connection from Firefox?

Tags: linux, networking, firefox, traffic-filtering

I want to find which files or data is downloaded while loading and interacting on a specific webpage.

How do I show every connection attempt from Firefox?

I would like to use command line tools (something like `ngrep` or `tcpdump` or the like). But if there is a better solution, please tell me.

Comment: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and/or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the firefox inspector. Open the page, press F12 then choose Network or Ctrl-Shift-Q to start the Network inspector directly. Then reload the page to see all of the network requests made, times, etc. Far more detail than you likely need.

If you want a lower-level command-line display, you'll want to look into `netstat`. You can filter by process id. For instance, `sudo netstat -ptc | grep FIREFOX_PID` will show all of the connection firefox makes, refreshing continuously (`c`). Not very useful though, lots of noise.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + Q will close the browser (on Microsoft Windows). Please update the shortcut to CTRL + SHIFT + E